# VBA CountIF is not counting the date

Tags: excel, vba

I am a VBA Beginner looking for some advice on COUNTIFS function.

I am trying to Count the amount of strings in a column, then check another column to only count those strings after todays date.

This is the line of code throwing up an error, any advice would be appreciated! :)

The error I get is...

Run-time error '1004':

Unable to get the CountIfs property of the WorksheetFunction class.

```
Hidden.Range("F" & p).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(APAC.Range("D2:D1000"), APAC.Range("D" & o).Value, APAC.Range("H" & o).Value, ">" & Date)
```

Comment: `Countifs(CriteriaRange1, Criteria1, CriteriaRange2, Criteria2)`.  Your third entry is not a range.  You may want to try it out as a formula on the worksheet first.

Comment: Thank you! I see what I was doing now, I was referencing 1 cell rather than the second range. This fixed it :)

`Hidden.Range("F" & p).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(APAC.Range("D2:D1000"), APAC.Range("D" & o).Value, APAC.Range("H2:H1000"), ">" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YY"))`